# How to force heatmap cells to be rectangular

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am using pcolormesh to create a heatmap.

```
heatmap = plt.pcolormesh(
    grid,
    edgecolors="k",
    cmap=colors.ListedColormap(
        [
            "white",
            "red",
            "blue",
            "green",
            "orange",
            "black",
            "purple",
            "yellow",
            "brown",
            "violet",
            "gray",
        ]
    ),
    linewidth=2,
)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("auto")
```

I want to set the cells shape to be rectangular. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you meant "square" cells, not "rectangular":

Set aspect to 1: `ax.set_aspect(1)`

[image: square cells]

aspect defines the Y/X ratio, so to have twice as high cells: `ax.set_aspect(2)`

[image: twice as high]

And twice as wide: `ax.set_aspect(1/2)`

[image: twice as wide]

Comment: Now that I have updated my post with the image of the heatmap in the default view I have, I want to force each cells to be rectangular. The cells change their shape based on aspect ration i.e. when I enlarge the window size then they can be rectangular but I want them to be rectangular in any window shape.

Comment: yes, but rectangular **how**? cells are always rectangular (not circle, triangle…)

Comment: Thank you so much, ax.set_aspect(1/2) did the trick for me.